# Android studio не отображает xml подсказки

Tags: android-studio, xml

**Android studio утратила способность отображать подсказки в xml файлах. Я пытался удалять кэш, перезагружать, удалять idea директорию.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Самое интересное, что в корневом элементе - RelativeLayout подсказки работают. Но в дочерних они не отображаются совсем.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Срочно нужна помощь. Я предпринял много мер, но пока ничего не помогло.**